# How to make server request when app goes in pause state in android?

Tags: android

I have an activity called otpverification which send request for OTP generation to server.but when activity goes in pause state like when I close app it is running in background In that situation I want to send server request .How can I do that

Comment: Use a service. a intent service probably

Comment: suggest some code for that

Comment: read https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: but how to check acitivity is in foreground or background

Comment: check lifecycle methods of the activity

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of operation its better if you use Service, follow this link "https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html" or modify this example according to your requirement

First create the Service class and register it in manifest file

```
public class MyService extends Service {
 @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
  return null;
  }
   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
// Let it continue running until it is stopped.
  Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  return START_STICKY;
}
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

Call this service from your activity like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }


   @Override
   public void startService(View view) {
      startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
}
   // Method to stop the service
   public void stopService(View view) {
      stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
}
}
```

Note - if you want to return any data from service to your activity use Broadcast receiver, click here for example https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/WeatherAPI

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use Asynchronous Http Client for http request.